# How to update an object in 'state' with react redux?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

In my reducer, suppose originally I have this state:

```
{
    "loading": false,
    "data": {
        "-L1LwSwW97KkwdSnYvsc": {
            "likeCount": 10,
            "liked": false,    // I want to update this property
            "commentCount": 5
        },
        "-L1EY2_fqzn7sM1Mbf_F": {
            "likeCount": 8,
            "liked": true,
            "commentCount": 22
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to update `liked` property inside `-L1LwSwW97KkwdSnYvsc` object, which is inside `data` object and make it `true`. This is what I've been trying, but apparently, it's wrong, because after I've updated the state, the `componentWillReceiveProps` function inside a component that listens to the state change does not get triggered:

```
var { data } = state;
data['-L1LwSwW97KkwdSnYvsc'].liked = !data['-L1LwSwW97KkwdSnYvsc'].liked;

return { ...state, data };
```

Could you please specify why it's wrong and how I should change it to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're mutating state! When you destructure:

```
var { data } = state;
```

It's the same as:

```
var data = state.data;
```

So when you do:

```
data[…].liked = !data[…].liked
```

You're still modifying `state.data` which is in turn mutating `state`. That's never good - use some nested spread syntax:

```
return { 
  ...state, 
  data: {
    ...state.data,
    '-L1LwSwW97KkwdSnYvsc': {
      ...state.data['-L1LwSwW97KkwdSnYvsc'],
      liked: !state.data['-L1LwSwW97KkwdSnYvsc'].liked
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Using spread operator is good until you start working with deeply nested state and/or arrays(remember spread operator does a shallow copy only).

I would rather recommend you starting working with [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) instead. It is a React recommendation and it will let your code more readable and bug free.

Example:

```
  import update from "immutability-helper";

  (...)

  const toggleLike = !state.data["-L1LwSwW97KkwdSnYvsc"].liked
  return update(state, {
    data: {
      "-L1LwSwW97KkwdSnYvsc": {
        like: {
          $set: toggleLike
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: I was looking for this but I couldn't seem to find it. It looks like it was moved to a different package. +1

Comment: React used to have an `react-addons-update` add-on, they deprecated it and started recommending this repo. (link https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html)